# Как посчитать сумму ячеек в таблице?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код такого вида:

```
var html = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="name"></td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td><td><input type="number" name="name"></td><td><input type="number" name="name"></td><td><input type="number" name="name" class="mat_count"></td><td><button class="remove">-</button></td></tr>'

$(function () {
    $('tbody').sortable()

    $('.addRow').click(function () {
        $('tbody').append(html)        
    })

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove()
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f041xL6v/
Как сделать, чтобы данные ячеек "стоимость" суммировалась и отображалась в инпуте "сумма"?
Пробовал несколько вариантов, найденных в сети - к успеху не пришёл(

Answer (score 0):

```
      var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $('.mat_count').length; i++){
           if($('.mat_count')[i].value != "")
              sum += parseInt($('.mat_count')[i].value);
        }
      $('.count')[0].value = parseInt(sum);
```

Смотря после какого действия необходимо обновлять сумму?

Comment: Foxey, после добавления строки
Спасибо!

Comment: $('.addRow').on('click', function(){
       var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $('.mat_count').length; i++){
           if($('.mat_count')[i].value != "")
              sum += parseInt($('.mat_count')[i].value);
        }
      $('.count')[0].value = parseInt(sum);
    })

Comment: А можно ещё сделать так, чтобы сумма уменьшалась при удалении строки?
Буду очень признателен

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fjpq26g5/

Comment: Foxy, огонь!
Спасибо!